# R legend missing

Tags: r, plot, charts, legend

How do I add a legend to my plot? Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
plot(check, main = "VIX vs SPY 1m StdDev") 
legend("topleft", legend = c("1 month SD", "VIX"))
```

[I've generated this plot using the above code but as you can see no legend can be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSfab.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please carefully read how to make a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not all `plot`s are the same. This does not look like a standard plot since it has a whole bunch of formatting and colours added automatically. I'm guessing your `check` object is something interesting created by a particular R package, that probably has its own unique method for adding a legend.

Comment: Damn... are you Jesus... you just solved this for me in 10 mins while I struggled with it for 3 days